Total and Sum of two columns in a single query
My requirement is similar to this question & answer PostgreSQL - Calculate SUM() of COUNT()
But need the total by another column
I have something similar to this
create table Item
(
     ItemID          INTEGER               not null,
     ItemCode        NCHAR(10)             not null,
     ItemName        NCHAR(10)             not null,
     constraint PK_ITEM primary key (ItemID)
);

create table Store
(
    StoreID             INTEGER             not null,
    StoreName           NCHAR(20)           not null,
    ItemID              INTEGER             not null,
    Location            NCHAR(20)           not null,
    constraint PK_STORE primary key (StoreID),
    foreign key (ItemID) references Item(ItemID)
);

insert into Item (ItemID,ItemCode,ItemName) Values (1,'abc','abc');
insert into Item (ItemID,ItemCode,ItemName) Values (2,'def','def');
insert into Item (ItemID,ItemCode,ItemName) Values (3,'ghi','ghi');

insert into Store (StoreID,StoreName,ItemID,Location) Values (1,'B1',1,'L1');
insert into Store (StoreID,StoreName,ItemID,Location) Values (2,'B2',2,'L2');
insert into Store (StoreID,StoreName,ItemID,Location) Values (3,'B3',1,'L3');
insert into Store (StoreID,StoreName,ItemID,Location) Values (4,'B4',2,'L1');
insert into Store (StoreID,StoreName,ItemID,Location) Values (5,'B5',3,'L2');
insert into Store (StoreID,StoreName,ItemID,Location) Values (6,'B6',2,'L3');
insert into Store (StoreID,StoreName,ItemID,Location) Values (7,'B7',3,'L1');
insert into Store (StoreID,StoreName,ItemID,Location) Values (8,'B8',1,'L3');
insert into Store (StoreID,StoreName,ItemID,Location) Values (9,'B9',2,'L1');

I have tried this
select count(I.ItemID), S.ItemID, I.ItemCode,  count(S.Location),S.Location
from Store S, Item I where S.ItemId=I.ItemID 
group by S.ItemID, I.ItemCode, S.Location ;

This results in this



count
itemid
itemcode
count
location




2
1
abc
2
L3


1
1
abc
1
L1


1
2
def
1
L3


2
2
def
2
L1


1
2
def
1
L2


1
3
ghi
1
L2


1
3
ghi
1
L1



I want something like this where the total displayed for itemId



count
itemid
itemcode
count
location




3
1
abc
2
L3


3
1
abc
1
L1


4
2
def
1
L3


4
2
def
2
L1


4
2
def
1
L2


2
3
ghi
1
L2


2
3
ghi
1
L1



or preferably like this



itemid
itemcode
count
location




1
abc
2
L3


1
abc
1
L1


1
Total
3
<-------


2
def
1
L3


2
def
2
L1


2
def
1
L2


2
Total
4
<-------


3
ghi
1
L2


3
ghi
1
L1


3
Total
2
<-------



How to achieve this?

add this as column in your query ,sum(cnt) over (partition by s.itemid )tot_cnt

You can have separated selects in a single query and combine the result using join or union. For the first expected output, you can query like below
select sq1.count, sq1.ItemID, sq2.ItemCode, sq2.count, sq2.Location from (
  select S1.ItemID, count(*)  as count
  from Store S1
  group by S1.ItemID
) sq1
inner join (
  select S2.ItemID, I.ItemCode, Count(*), S2.Location from Store S2 
  inner join Item I
  on S2.ItemId = I.ItemId
  group by S2.ItemID, I.ItemCode, S2.Location
) sq2
on sq1.ItemID = sq2.ItemID
order by sq2.ItemID, sq2.ItemCode;

For the second result, you can use this query
select * from (
  select S.ItemID, I.ItemCode, Count(*), S.Location from Store S 
  inner join Item I
  on S.ItemId = I.ItemId
  group by S.ItemID, I.ItemCode, S.Location
  union
  select  S2.ItemID, 'Total'  as itemcode, Count(*), null
  from Store S2
  group by S2.ItemID
) sq
order by sq.ItemID, sq.ItemCode;


You can use the ROLLUP clause:
    select I.ItemID,  case when S.Location is null then 'Total' else I.ItemCode end as ItemCode, count(*) as count,  S.Location
    from #Store S
         inner join
         #Item I 
         on S.ItemId=I.ItemID 
    group by  I.ItemID,I.ItemCode, rollup(S.Location)
    order by I.ItemId, S.Location NULLS LAST

But you have to make sure that the S.Location will not have nulls (because I used it to flag the subtotal row).
Honestly, subtotals and grand totals etc are better handled by the presentation layer (reporting tool, or a form, etc..), because the SQL engines have limited facilities to deal with myriads of display options users might ask for.

This is clever! It seems all those columns are never NULL according to the table definition.

The following query uses GROUPING SETS to achieve the OP's preferred results:
SELECT
  s.itemid,
  COALESCE(i.itemcode, 'Total') AS itemcode,
  COUNT(i.itemid),
  COUNT(s.location),
  s.location
FROM
  store s
  JOIN item i ON s.itemid = i.itemid
GROUP BY
  GROUPING sets ((s.itemid, i.itemcode, s.location), (s.itemid))
ORDER BY
  s.itemid,
  s.location;




itemid
itemcode
count
count-2
location




1
abc
1
1
L1


1
abc
2
2
L3


1
Total
3
3



2
def
2
2
L1


2
def
1
1
L2


2
def
1
1
L3


2
Total
4
4



3
ghi
1
1
L1


3
ghi
1
1
L2


3
Total
2
2




